# resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field

Tags: java, jax-rs

This [example works](http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/12/16/jax-rs-hello-world-example-with-wildfly/) fine for me in my eclipse. However, when I have changed the Person class to the following :

```
package com.thejavageek.jaxrs.model;

public class Person {


private int userSelectList;

    public int getUserSetSelectList() {
        return userSelectList;
    }

    public void setUserSetSelectList(int userSelectList) {
        this.userSelectList = userSelectList;
    }





    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "Person [userSelectSet=" + userSelectList + "]";
    }

}
```

And I tested by passing the JSON like the following :

[image]

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "userSelectList" (class com.thejavageek.jaxrs.model.Person), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "userSetSelectList"])
 at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@6418702f; line: 1, column: 20] (through reference chain: com.thejavageek.jaxrs.model.Person["userSelectList"])
```

Why is it that the example form the link I shared above works fine and not this one?

Comment: try to use  `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` at the class level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your json, change "userSelectList" to "userSetSelectList", or change your setter to "setUserSelectList"